# Pass SSIS parameter into OPENQUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, openedge

Please I need help passing a parameter in SSIS into an 'OPENQUERY', to test the query I'm using the script below but getting errors:

Script:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @Date varchar(11)
SELECT  @Date = '28 Nov 2018'
SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([TEST], ''SELECT * FROM PUB.TEST
WHERE Test_Date >= ''''' + @Date + ''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST" returned message "[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Invalid date string (7497)".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM PUB.TEST 
WHERE Test_Date >= '28 Nov 2018'" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST".
```

Script in SSIS OLE DB Source should look like this:

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @Date varchar(11)
SELECT  @Date = ?
SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([TEST], ''SELECT * FROM PUB.TEST
WHERE Test_Date >= ''''' + @Date + ''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Comment: [MSDASQL is becoming deprecated. It will not be ported to 64 bit platforms, and will not receive any feature enhancements in future releases](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2007/11/10/msdasql-oledb-provider-for-odbc-drivers/)

Comment: If you run your first block of code, does it work successfully? This helps us identify is the problem with your OQ syntax and/or string building or is it the parameterization within SSIS.

Comment: You might also be better served by creating a Variable within SSIS and use Expressions to build the string there.

Comment: @billinkc I managed to find the problem, it was silly error and it's got to do with how OpenEdge DB handles date literals. Merely changing the Date variable to '28-Nov-2018' fixed the problem. However your advice on MSDASQL being deprecated is very useful, I now build the SQL statement using a SSIS variable expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend script to below, problem was with date format

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @Date varchar(11)
SELECT  @Date = '28-Nov-2018'
SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([TEST], ''SELECT * FROM PUB.TEST
WHERE Test_Date >= ''''' + @Date + ''''''')'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```